# echo -n aWord | md5 not returning expected result

Tags: bash, shell, command-line

When I pass this line `echo -n aWord | md5` directly in shell I get the expected result - same as PHP `md5('aWord')` - but when I call the code from a file I get a different string.

Please help.

Comment: Can you share the relevant parts of the shell script that aren't working?

Comment: Show the file you are using, please. Also, which `md5` command are you using here?

Comment: Does `echo -n` behave differently in a shell and a script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you get following md5s:

```
=$ echo -n aWord | md5sum
a72ef25b2fa8080e6e0643c967284842  -
```

And from file:

```
=$ cat test.file 
aWord

=$ md5sum test.file 
1d03663ed556e850007c886ce5ad3ade  test.file
```

This is because there is additional character in file - new line character:

```
=$ hexdump -C test.file 
00000000  61 57 6f 72 64 0a                                 |aWord.|
00000006
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment but I do get the same result from a file than from the command line :

```sh
$ echo -n 'aWord' | md5sum
a72ef25b2fa8080e6e0643c967284842  -
$ echo -n 'aWord' > file
$ md5sum file 
a72ef25b2fa8080e6e0643c967284842  file
```